# How can I get the Google Maps embeded labels positions or placements?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, label, marker

I am developing a demo that want to put some my labels on top of Google Maps. In my case, I need to avoid my labels intersecting with the existing Google Maps labels, e.g., cities.

My question is that how can I get the placement position of the cities labels in Google Maps? Both pixel position and longitude-latitude position are ok.

For example, how can I know where is the position of the label "Los Angeles" at zoom level 3? Is there any API to get it? Is it possible to know it?

It is really important to me.

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you read the maps API documentation? Have you tried to write any code so far? If so please post it.

Comment: Hi Sir, I read some google maps API. But I only find I can edit the labels created by myself. But my question is how to get the positions of the labels created by Google. So I can avoid overlaps between my markers and Google maps labels. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to access these informations